# Jquery bind or on is not working for custom event

Tags: jquery

I have a JSP file containing an `iframe`. On the parent JSP some `.js` (Timer.js) file is referred in which a custom event is created using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    RegEvent();
    $('#time-text').trigger('updateDBTime');
});

function RegEvent()
{
    $('#time-text').bind('updateDBTime',function(e){
        alert('called');            
    }); 

}
```

`#time-text` is an span on parent JSP.

The above code works fine.

Now I want to trigger this event from the `.js` file referred in `iframe`. I tried:

`$('#time-text',window.parent.document).trigger('updateDBTime');`

and

`$('#time-text').trigger('updateDBTime');`

Both versions don't work and log no error on the console.

I am using **`jquery-1.9.0.min.js`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work:

`parent.$({selector}).trigger( 'eventName' );`

the event triggered inside the iframe will be detected in the parent document.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
$(window.parent.document.getElementById('time-text')).trigger('updateDBTime');
```